# How do I attach a column that has minimum and maximum?

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a table "A" as follows:

```
     ID |   Quantity
------------------------
     1  |     3333
     1  |     4444
     1  |     5555
     2  |     2344
```

I want to make a new table as follows:

```
     ID |   Quantity   |  Max(Quantity)  |   Min(Quantity)
-----------------------------------------------------------
     1  |     3333     |     5555        |     3333
     1  |     4444     |     5555        |     3333 
     1  |     5555     |     5555        |     3333
     2  |     2344     |     2344        |     2344
```

(Maximum and minimum are calculated with respect to 'ID')

How do I code this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use analytic functions:

```
select id, quantity,
       max(quantity) over (partition by id) as max_quantity,
       min(quantity) over (partition by id) as min_quantity
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select 
    ID,
    Quantity,
    B.Max_Quantity,
    B.Min_Quantity
From
    A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    select
      ID,
      MAX(Quantity) as Max_Quantity,
      MIN(Quantity) as Min_Quantity
    From
      A
    Group by
      ID
) B ON B.ID = A.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

select id ,quantity
from t
where quantity= (select max(quantity) from t) 
and quantity= (select min(quantity) from t);

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If quantity=max and quantity=min then you have that max=min, so all values are equal?